# AFNetworking - ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: xcode, afnetworking

I have an Xcode project with Cocoa Pods installed which I added a tvOS single view app target. I shared with the tvOS target all the pod installed. When I build and run my iOS target everything is ok, but when I run the tvOS target I get this error

"ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

So after searching on the web I found a solution to this error. If I go to the Build Settings for the tvOS target and under Valid Architectures I remove arm64 and type armv7 the error disappears but then when i run the project i get this: the file couldn't be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you must sure you're opening the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj file.
2. Then, open your project folder and run command `pod install` and reopen .xcworkspace file it will fix your issue.